# Perl CGI script response code

Tags: android, perl, cgi

I have a Perl script that accepts HTTP GET requests and returns JSON content back. However, when I call the script from an Android app using Volley, I'm getting the following error:

```
E/Volley﹕ [1178] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://
```

If I use curl to check the script, I get this response:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 95.142.152.194...
* Connected to pro.url.co.uk (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /cgi-bin/api.pl HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: pro.url.co.uk
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 01 Aug 2015 07:18:42 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Set-Cookie: DYNSRV=lin218; path=/
< 
{"error":"2000","description":"an action header is required"}
```

Here is the perl code:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $json = JSON->new->utf8;
my $header_type = "application/json";
my $header_status = "200";
my $output = $json->encode({
  "error" => "2000",
  "description" => "an action header is required",
});
print $cgi->header(
  -type => $header_type,
  -charset => "utf-8",
  -status => $header_status
);
print $output;
print "\n";
```

I'm not the world's most competent perl dev so if anyone has any hints, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: When you get the 500 error, what gets written to the web server error log?

Comment: pro.url.co.uk 80.229.30.33 - - [01/Aug/2015:08:04:35 +0100] "GET /cgi-bin/api.pl HTTP/1.1" 200 72 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.2; XT1032 Build/LXB22.46-28.1)" 80.229.30.33

Comment: That looks like the access log, not the error log. And can you edit these additions into the question, rather than adding them in comments.

Comment: Wait ... that line doesn't match the Volley request you mentioned, it contains a status code of 200.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I had to include a couple of empty lines after the header to prevent apache from generating a 500 error.

So try this code:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $json = JSON->new->utf8;
my $header_type = "application/json";
my $header_status = "200";
my $output = $json->encode({
  "error" => "2000",
  "description" => "an action header is required",
});
print $cgi->header(
  -type => $header_type,
  -charset => "utf-8",
  -status => $header_status
),
 "\n\n",
 $output,
 "\n";
```